# What's wrong with this code which prints the value at address obtained after converting an integer to an integer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, termination

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int* p = &a;
    int** q = &p;
    printf("\n%d %d %d", a, *p, **q);

    int y = (int*)2000;
    printf("%d", y);

    /*
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", a, *p, **q, *((int*)2000)); //Error line.
    */

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs. However, if you uncomment the commented code, the code still compiles but terminates before printing the result of the last `printf` command.

My 2 questions are:

1. If `*((int*)2000)` is a perfectly valid code like `(int*)2000` (i.e., an integer turned into an address/pointer to get the value at that address), why does program stop before the end if `*((int*)2000)` is present?
2. Why doesn't this code print the values of `a`, `*p`, and `**q` before terminating the program (they are printed before trying to print `*((int*)2000))`) ?

Comment: What do you think would exist at the virtual address `2000`? What makes you think it's even a valid address?

Comment: `*((int*)2000)` is dereferencing an invalid address: you get segv when evaluating the arguments

Comment: `int y = (int*)2000` is like `int y = 2000` with more warnings.

Comment: add a \n to the end of the first printf, or call `fflush(stdout);` before the crash line, and the first output will occur. User programs cannot readmemory that does not belong to them at will, as that would be a memory segmentation violation. Hence the segfault you are most likely receiving.

Comment: Did you mean to write `int* y = (int*)2000;` by chance? Because if not, all you did was take the number 2000, cast it to an int-pointer, then cast it back to an int. As Jean-François said, all you did was add warnings.

Comment: "if *((int*)2000) is a perfectly valid code" is a weak/false premise.  `(int*)2000` is not certainly valid C code.

Comment: @chux The question is about the line that is commented out, it contains `*((int*)2000)`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for adding clarity.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I would not bet that `(int*)2000 == 2000`, because there's no guarantee that converting an int to a pointer and backwould result in the same number.  Of course, nowadays it works exactly as you said with mainstream CPU architectures.  However this was not guaranteed on [old 8086 memory models](http://www.cyberplusindia.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/16/memory-models-and-types-of-pointers/) with a 16 bit int, and a 20 bit pointer represented with two overlapping 16 bit components.  Not sure neither that there are no exotic microcontrollers left with weird addressing schemes ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `*((int*)2000)` is not "perfectly valid code". The result of converting an integer to a pointer is implementation-defined. It's likely that in your implementation, `(int*)2000` results in an invalid pointer. Trying to dereference an invalid pointer produces undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen. When you ran the program with the `printf` line uncommented, it happened to result in a segmentation violation, because the resulting pointer pointed to unaccessible memory. If you'd used some other integer, it might have resulted in a valid pointer, and then you'd see the contents of that memory location.
2. All the parameters to a function call have to be evaluated before the function is called. The above error is happening while evaluating the parameters to `printf()`, so the program stops before the function is called. As a result, nothing is printed.

Answer (score 2):

**Non problem**

The expression `(int*)2000` is used in several places. You take an arbitrary integer and convert it to a pointer type. This is allowed according to C11 standard, section 6.3.2.3:

> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not
>      be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>      type, and might be a trap representation

So you are sure to get a pointer, but you have no guarantee that it is valid.

**Potential problem**

Then you take a first risk, because you convert a pointer type to a plain integer:

```
int y = (int*)2000;
```

We've already seen that the casted expression `(int*)2000` is a pointer type.  According to the C standard, in the section 6.3.2.3 about pointer conversions:

> 6. Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. **If the
>      result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>      undefined**. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>      integer type.

So there is a risk of undefined behavior. This means that it could potentially crash or stop the program with a fatal error. But if your output shows the value of 2000, this means that the result can be represented in the integer type and everything's fine, at least with your specific compiler (it's not a universal guarantee: another compiler could make this crash, even if the risk is low).

**Most probable problem**

When you uncomment your final statement, you have a very dangerous expression in it:

```
*((int*)2000)
```

You dereference a pointer that you have obtained by conversion.  However, we have seen above, that the pointer `(int*)2000` might be invalid.  Unfortunately, the C standard, section 6.5.3.2 is very clear about the risks:

> 4. (...) If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

And here it certainly is:  on most modern computers, the operating system assigns a virtual memory address space to a process.  The operating system then keeps track of the valid address ranges and the invalid one. In addition, some OS security mechanism make the relevant address location of your code random, so to avoid hacking exploits, which could make use of fixed addresses.   So if your pointer would not point to a valid address (most probable situation here), there is a big chance that the operating catches an invalid memory access, which triggers a fatal error.

Another frequent situation would be an alignment issue: modern CPUs have alignment constraints for integers. For example, an integer cannot start on an odd address, because it would be a problem for the CPU to load it fast into its register. Alignment problems also cause crashes.

But all this are only potential examples of undefined behavior. Another case, could be that everything seems to work fine, despite the invalid pointer. It's just that a garbage integer value would be printed.

**Conclusion**

Code can be perfectly valid, but nevertheless result in perfectly undefined behavior. So, whenever you want to dereference a pointer, first think: can you be sure that it's always valid ?

Comment: There is very well a guarantee whether the resulting pointer is valid. It is just not given by the standard, but the implementation. Nevertheless, the standard requires the implementation to specify the behaviour.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite the result of conversion btw pointer and int are indeed implementation dependent (C11 annex J.3).  However the case of the impossible representation is mentioned explicitly as undefined (and not unspecified nor implementation defined) both in the C11 text body and in annex J.2. The term is used consistently in the standard and refers to unpredictable results including potential termination of the program.  I must admit that I never encountered the case for such a conversion, but it cannot be excluded (therefore my wording "potential").

Comment: I'm quite sure I underwstand what you mean with "impossible represntation". Of course what an integer value converted to a pointer means depends on the implementation (and possibly platform) and on managed environments like Linux, Windows, etc, it's UB to use such a value. Nevertheless, on typical bare-metal embedded platforms (or some Linux systems with MMIO mapped to user-space), it could in fact be well defined. Going further: An implementation can well define what the standard leave as UB. Without this, C on bare-metal/kernel drivers/… would be quite impossible (or we had to use Assembler)

Comment: "I'm quite sure" -> "I'm **not** quite sure"

Answer (score 0):

The seconnd printf when the parameters are eventuated compiler does not dereference the invalid address and it just casts the pointer back to the integer.

The third one dereferences it before passing to the printf and you invoke an UB

But such a casts are in common use in the uC development. For example:

`*(volatile uint32_t *)(0x40000000U + 0x08000000U + 0x00000000U) = 0x02;`

sets the pin 0 of the STM32F3 GPIOC in the alternate mode.

Comment: A segfault is not guaranteed.  That's actually undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen.  As an example, on small arduino devices, CP/M, MS-DOS Tiny, Small and Compact modes, you'll probably print something, it'll just be a garbage value from the middle of memory.

Comment: You may mean the second `printf`, not the first. There are three in OP’s code, including the commented-out one. However, none of the `printf` calls includes a cast. There is no cast to integer in the entire program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes the second and the commented one (third)